# Paste .htaccess code above or below the WordPress htaccess code?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to add some code to my .htaccess file. But I am unclear where to paste it because my .htaccess file has WordPress code in it.

**CODE A: Wordpress code**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Can someone show me where to insert "CODE B" (see below)? Should this go above or below the WordPress .htaccess code? If it should go above, would I need to remove the `RewriteEngine On` from the Wordpress code and put it at the very top? Please reply with code so I can visually see the correct way to do this.

**CODE B: My code**

```
#Specify IP Allowed to Login
<Files wp-login.php>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 12.345.67.890
</Files>
```

---

**CODE C: Is the following .htaccess order correct? If not, can you show me the correct order?** Should `RewriteEngine On` be near the top ?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

#Specify IP Allowed to Login
<Files wp-login.php>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 12.345.67.891
</Files>

#STRONG HTACCESS PROTECTION
<Files ~ "^.*\.([Hh][Tt][Aa])">
 order allow,deny
 deny from all
 satisfy all
</Files>

<files wp-config.php>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</files>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

#Prevent directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

#Redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#Redirect index.html
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#Redirect IP Address
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^123\.456\.789\.999$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

#Force Trailing Slash
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1/ [L,R=301] 

#Stop Hotlinking
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)domain.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|bmp|zip|rar|mp3|flv|swf|xml|php|png|css|pdf)$ - [F]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying to use `<Files>` directive you can combine your existing WP .htaccess with another rewrite rule with similar effect like this:

```
#STRONG HTACCESS PROTECTION
<Files ~ "^.*\.([Hh][Tt][Aa])">
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
</Files>

<files wp-config.php>
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</files>

Options All -Indexes
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#Redirect index.html
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#Redirect IP Address
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^123\.456\.789\.999$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

#Force Trailing Slash
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1/ [L,R=301] 

#Stop Hotlinking
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)domain.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|bmp|zip|rar|mp3|flv|swf|xml|php|png|css|pdf)$ - [F]

# only allow 12.345.67.890 IP to access /wp-login.php or /wp-admin/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(wp-login\.php|wp-admin/) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=12.345.67.890
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Thanks anubhava. I have more <Files> directive stuff to insert and and would like to understand where to insert these without combining with existing WP .htaccess - Can you demonstrate where to insert <Files> directive ? Also where do you insert `Options +FollowSymLinks` ?

Comment: anubhava, I am still unsure of the correct order of .htaccess - can you check "CODE C" in my post above? I just watched some .htaccess tutorials and I am still confused. I was told redirect rules should be near the top, so would I put all the redirect rules above `<Files>` therefore WordPress .htaccess code would be at the very bottom?

Comment: anubhava will I need to use `Options +FollowSymLinks` ? If yes, where would I put this?

Comment: `Options All` in my answer already includes `+FollowSymLinks`